# Why does webpack 2 bundle use `eval()` to wrap code?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I am just learning webpack.  I notice in the resulting bundle.js it uses eval like this (when in "Development" mode, not "Production" which produces something completely different):

```
function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
eval("\r\nvar Component = (function () {\r\n    function Component() {\r\n        this.myProperty = \"Hello\";\r\n    }\r\n    return Component;\r\n}());\r\nexports.Component = Component;\r\n//# sourceMappingURL=component.js.map//# sourceMappingURL=data:application/json;charset=utf-8;base64,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");

/***/ },
```

What is the reasoning behind this?  It just seems a little odd to be using the eval function.

This is what the production version looks like:

```
!function(n){function t(e){if(r[e])return r[e].exports;var o=r[e]={i:e,l:!1,exports:{}};return n[e].call(o.exports,o,o.exports,t),o.l=!0,o.exports}var r={};return t.m=n,t.c=r,t.i=function(n){return n},t.d=function(n,r,e){t.o(n,r)||Object.defineProperty(n,r,{configurable:!1,enumerable:!0,get:e})},t.n=function(n){var r=n&&n.__esModule?function(){return n.default}:function(){return n};return t.d(r,"a",r),r},t.o=function(n,t){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(n,t)},t.p="",t(t.s=1)}([function(n,t,r){"use strict";var e=function(){function n(){this.myProperty="Hello"}return n}();t.Component=e},function(n,t,r){"use strict";var e=r(0),o=function(){function n(){this.myComponent=new e.Component,console.log(this.myComponent.myProperty)}return n}();t.App=o}]);
```

Comment: It's a lot faster. Try the other options too and you'll see better. There are also differences in rebundling speed and quality. That's the tradeoff.

Comment: Thanks, spent an hour searching why my generated code looks like shit and found the answer :)

Comment: If you do not want to wrap each module in `eval` in development mode you should provide following (webpack 4) `devtool: 'nosources-source-map'`

Comment: (webpack 4) `devtool: false` also works

Answer (score 16):

It depends upon your `devtool` preference. Typically, `devtool` value should be set to one of the following:
`false`, `"source-map"`, `"nosources-source-map"`.

Refer to the Webpack configuration for more details: [Webpack configuration for devtool](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/devtool/). Beware that different `devtool` values affect your bundling performance.

Essentially, pick any value that marks `production` column as **yes**.

Using `eval()` to wrap the code is the fastest way of bundling with source-maps. It doesn't do the complex code to source-map mapping and thus provide fast incremental build.

Comment: Which `devtool` value prevents the `eval` wrapping? I'd like to debug the code easily.

Comment: What did you mean by "It doesn't do the complex code to source-map mapping"? When I use the `eval` option and decode the base64 source map at the end of the `eval`, it's still the same source map as the one without `eval`. How exactly is `eval` faster?